# 你在那裏可以安心**地**生活下去 Why not use 的

Tags: grammar

你在那裏可以安心**地**生活下去

I thought the correct word should be 的. How is 生活 a verb/action? I know 安心 is describing the type of 生活, but 生活 is a noun.

Comment: Here 生活 means live, as in to "live" one's life.

Comment: So in this case it's a verb? Thanks.

Comment: Neither. Don't think Chinese in terms of Western grammar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, 生活 in this sentence is indeed a verb, which means 活着, 过(日子).

No, you could not use **的**, because 你在那裏可以安心**的**生活下去 is not correct. You must have another verb if you use 的 before a noun 生活. 你在那裏可以**过**安心**的**生活.

生活 can be a noun. For example,

他家生活有困难。

他过着贫穷的生活。

Answer (score 0):

Both 的 and 地 are correct. Often multiple characters serve the same function in any one situation.

Comment: No. 你在那裏可以安心**的**生活下去. It is not correct. You must have another verb if you use 的 for a noun 生活. 你在那裏可以**过**安心**的**生活.

Comment: Huh? It appears that you need a better understanding of Chinese. In Chinese, 的 is *always* followed by a "noun."

Answer (score 0):

的 is followed by nouns, it helps the former adjective to describe a noun, e.g. 可爱的人们 (lovely people), 开心的一天 (a happy day).

地 is followed by verbs, it the former adverb to describe an action, e.g. 愉快地玩耍 (play happily), 快速地跑步 (run fast).

生活 can be both noun and verb, if it is a noun, it means "life"; if it is a verb, it means "to live". But if you want to express "what kind of life you want to live", you have to use 过XX的生活, instead of 生活XX的生活.

In your situation, if you interpret 生活 as a noun, this sentence will have no verb, you will only have to nouns here, so it has to be a verb. The answer of @PdotWang has provided the correct way of saying this sentence if you want to use 安心的 to describe 生活.